# Add second column to order by mysql in a group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat, find-in-set

I have this query I made based on someone else question here.
`SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET( score, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score ASC) FROM EventPlayerResult WHERE eventId = 'EventTest0') ) AS position FROM EventPlayerResult WHERE eventId = 'EventTest0' ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 10`

It gives me a leaderboard for the top 10 players. But when I run it, if 2 players has the same score, I need it to filter by another column (energyLeft). So I tried to add    , energyLeft DESC inside of my GROUP_CCONCAT but it doesnt change anything. im not familiar with group concat and find in set. So where should I add the logic to order by energyLeft after ordering by score.

I tried something like this :
`SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET( score, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score ASC, energyLeft DESC) FROM EventPlayerResult WHERE eventId = 'EventTest0') ) AS position FROM EventPlayerResult WHERE eventId = 'EventTest0' ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the player and not the score inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` so that the players are ranked by `score` first and then by `energyLeft`.

Assuming there is a column like `player_id` in the table:

```
SELECT *, 
       FIND_IN_SET( 
         player_id, 
         ( 
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(player_id ORDER BY score ASC, energyLeft DESC) FROM EventPlayerResult WHERE eventId = 'EventTest0'
         ) 
       ) AS position 
FROM EventPlayerResult 
WHERE eventId = 'EventTest0' 
ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Just tested it, and it seems to be sorting by playerId now instead of score/energyLeft, also tried by having score in the find_in_set and playerid in group_concat, but then all my positions were 0. same if i invert score/playerid. so im assuming i need to have both the same column in find in set and group concat.

Comment: @DrDoom `GROUP_CONCAT(player_id ORDER BY score ASC, energyLeft DESC)` returns all the player_ids sorted by score ASC, energyLeft DESC. You are doing something wrong. Post sample data.

Comment: Just tested again, and it seems to work. but i have 2 rows at position 0 that doesnt make sense, but if i ignore those. everything else is fine.

PlayerId      Score     energyleft    position
Test10           100        1            0
Test2           90        25            0
Test3           6        20            1
Test4           9        16            2
Test5           13        12            3
Test6          18        10            4
Test18           19        5            5
Test11           22        100            6
Test111           22        90            7

Comment: so i think ill just use your way and ignore position 0

Comment: @DrDoom you should not get 0 as position. This is wrong. FIND_IN_SET() returns 0 only if the id is not there in the list. Also, if you want highest scores ranked first why do you use ORDER BY score ASC inside GROUP_CONCAT()? It should be ORDER BY score DESC. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nPctBdTP6HqZ5he9BgtMyJ/0

Comment: for the score, i use ASC and DESC depending on the event, some event use time (so we need smallest value) and other use points(so we need biggest value) . and yeah its super weird to get position 0, but i was not familiar with find_in_set, found it online while searching

Comment: I guess i could explain what im trying to do instead.  Im doing a leaderboard where you need to see the top 10 players, and your position and the +/- 5 position around you. so I could get the players that are position 1-10 and (x-10 to x+10) (x being the player position)

Comment: I added Having position > 0 to my query to remove the rows at position 0, hoping this will do, but not confident about it haha

Comment: @DrDoom what you mention in your last comments have nothing to do with the requirement as you describe it in your question.